# Odd behavior with CSV file source SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I am seeing an odd behavior with an SSIS package getting data from a `.csv` file.

The `file source` completes with without error, yet no rows are passed along to the next transformation. But if I enable the data viewer, data gets pumped to the next transformation as expected.

I am using VS 2015, SQL Server 2014.

The transformation after the `file source` is a `fuzzy grouping` transformation.

The data has some columns wrapped in quotes, other not:

```
Id, location

1, Mackinaw City
2, "Mobile, AL"
3, NOLA
```

My guess is I need to tweak the files source. So far it's just that, a guess.